# extjs grid panel deselect

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

I have a two grids made with ExtJs. One is rendered to a tab panel. Other (saying it result grid) is rendered to a window which is shown after AJAX call and datastore of result grid is reloaded after each AJAX call.

However after window containing result grid is closed, i cannot deselect rows of grid on tabPanel.

Thanks

Comment: Not enough information or code here. Try adding a `rowdeselect` and `rowselect` listeners to your `SelectionModel` and see if the events are firing at all.